# Proving that $|z-1|-|z+1|=1$ its an hyperbola, and $\Re(1-z)=|z|$ its an ellipse.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Proving that $|z-1|-|z+1|=1$ its an hyperbola, and $\Re(1-z)=|z|$ its an ellipse.
If $z\in \mathbb C$

I cant see why there are a hyperobla and an ellipse respct.

Comment: I think you have to write out the imaginary and real part then do some squaring.

Comment: I think you have a hyperbola and a parabola there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To show that $|z-1|-|z+1|=1$ is a hyperbola**

Let $a=|z-1|, b=|z+1|$ where $z=x+iy$.
Hence 
$a^2=(x-1)^2+y^2$ and $ b^2=(x+1)^2+y^2$.

Given equation:
$\qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad a-b=1\qquad\qquad $
Multiply by $a+b$ and swapping sides:
$\qquad a+b=a^2-b^2\qquad $
Adding:
$\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad 2a=1+a^2-b^2=1-4x$
  Squaring:
$$4a^2=(1-4x)^2\\
4((x-1)^2+y^2)=1-8x+16x^2\\
12x^2-y^2=4\\
\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}-\frac {y^2}{2^2}=1$$
which is a hyperbola.

*NB - the method above avoids messy square roots*

**To show that $\Re (1-z)=|z|$ is a parabola**

Squaring both sides: $(1-x)^2=x^2+y^2\Rightarrow y^2=-2ax+1$ which is a parabola.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you an idea :

$Re(1-z) = Re (1 - x - iy) = 1 - x $

On the other hand,  $ |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $

So, we can write :

$ (1-x)^2 = x^2 + y^2 $

Then you can rearrange the last part..

Answer (score 1):

The set of points whose difference of distances to  fixed points, the foci ($(-1,0),(1,0)$ respectively here )is constant, is a hyperbola. Here $|z-1|$ is the distance to -1 and $|z+1|$ is the distance to $-1$.